# how to get most popular results first in elastic-search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm learning elastic search,
I wanted to ask if there is any way to get most searched results first,
like:
 by altering the documents and updating a value of em with scores,
using some kind of formula or something else

thanks community :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have that out of the box but you can indeed modify a document and increase the number of views when a user clicks on a result then use that field as part of the score ([`function_score`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) might help for this).